# What is offsets.length or spans.length in the layoutMajorAxis(int targetSpan, int axis, int[] offsets, int[] spans) method?

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, paragraph, jeditorpane

Here is a little research that I have done and the answer below was given to me by @StanislavL

Check the tutorial  http://java-sl.com/editor_kit_tutorial_views.html

About the method

protected void layoutMajorAxis(int targetSpan, int axis, int[] offsets, int[] spans)

In fact it defines positions and spans of children.
Let's consider layoutMajorAxis for a paragraph. So we layout rows of the paragraph
targetSpan is amount of space we would like to achieve (in our case is paragraph height, it could be e.g. page height or table cell height ). Let's consider simple case the height is JEditorPane's width 100 pixels. 
So we should calculate where each row will begin (offsets) and how much space it require (spans).
axis is Y_AXIS

so if we e.g. call super.layoutMajorAxis for the paragraph and then change offsets to be 5, 10, 15 etc. we will have rows overlapping.

But if we consider layoutMajorAxis for a paragraph's row (e.g. our text contains bold word so the row has 3 child elements).

In this case targetSpan is owner paragraph's width, offsets are starts of each element spans are sizes of each text element.

**Question:** 1.Does offsets.length method give the number of 'elements' in the offset 'array' as the array.length method does (with first 'element' being of index 0) or is it the total sum of the offset [] array. e.g following the example on the link, the offset on Y-axis is {10,30,50} such that offsets.length = 10+30+50 which is 90? or it changes depending on the specific child view one is referring to?

2.if my major axis is y-axis,on this method, will also the span on this specific method be referring to y-axis? If this is so, then offsets on the x-axis  can change ,will therefore offsets of the x-axis be dealt with in layoutMinorView() method?

corrections are welcome.
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The offsets and spans arrays size is defined by amount of child views.

Suppose paragraph has 3 rows of text. Then offsets and spans arrays lengths are 3.

You should define offsets (position in pixels for each row). Normally the first offsets starts from 0 (if there is no margin).

Spans reflects size of each child view (again in pixels).

In case of paragraph suppose you have 3 equal rows with heights=12. No margins.

So after the call of

```
protected void layoutMajorAxis(int targetSpan, int axis, int[] offsets, int[] spans)
```

should return offsets [0, 12, 24] and spans [12, 12, 12].

If e.g. 2nd row contains a text fragment with height 20 (bigger font) the offsets and spans should be

offsets [0, 12, 32] and spans [12, 20, 12].

Comment: Yeah Thanks! I now see the subtleties and ambiguities of this method...span is different depending if I add text as a batch through insertString() or dynamically tying text..many thanks.